# match array map index to array value 'id'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im struggling to make a select all checkbox for my array map function. so far here is the result.[image: check all]

heres my select all function

```
const handleSelectAll = e => {
        setIsCheckAll(!isCheckAll);
        setSelected2(tradein?.data.map((li) => li.id));
        if (isCheckAll) {
          setSelected2([]); 
        }
      };
```

```
    const handleChange2 = event => {
        var updatedList = [...selected2];
               
        if (event.target.checked) {
            updatedList = [...selected2, event.target.value];
        } else {
            updatedList.splice(selected2.indexOf(event.target.value), 1);
        }
        setSelected2(updatedList)
    }
```

when the select all checked i need to push all the tradein array id value to the selected2 array.

heres the console log when selected all
[image: selected all]

but when i render with this code

```
<TableCell style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}><input type='checkbox'  onChange={handleSelectAll} checked={isCheckAll}/></TableCell>
{tradein?.data.map((ad, id)=>{
                            return (
                                <>
                                 <TableBody key={id}>
                                    <TableRow >
                                        <TableCell >
                                            <input type='checkbox'
                                            onChange={handleChange2} 
                                            key={id} 
                                            value={ad.id} 
                                            checked={selected2[ad.id]}/>
                                        </TableCell>
                                 </TableBody>
```

the first index is not checked.
any help would be so much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use array includes

```
checked={selected2.includes(ad.id)}/>
```

use filter to remove

```
    const handleChange2 = event => {
        var updatedList = [...selected2];
               
        if (event.target.checked) {
            updatedList = [...selected2, event.target.value];
        } else {
            updatedList = updatedList.filter(item => item !== event.target.value); // here changed
        }
        setSelected2(updatedList)
    }
```

Try 2

```
const handleChange2 = event => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        setSelected2(prev => [...prev, event.target.value])
    } else {
        setSelected2(prev => prev.filter(item => item !== event.target.value))
    }
}
```

Code

```js
const App = () => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);

const handleChange = value => {
    if (!selected.includes(value)) {
        setSelected(prev => [...prev, value])
    } else {
        setSelected(prev => prev.filter(item => item !== value))
    }
}

    return (
        <div>
            <input
              type='checkbox'
              onChange={() => handleChange(21)} 
              checked={selected.includes(21)}
            /> 21
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: it works! but now when i click it wont uncheck and added the value twice, not removing the checked value. i added my handle check function above. thanks

Comment: @pandu please use filter, answer updated

Comment: still the same, its continue adding the value i clicked and the box wont check or uncheck. here the log ``` Array(6)

Comment: @pandu updated again added `updatedList = `

Comment: @pandu did you added `updatedList = ` ?

Comment: yes i added the `updatedList =` and it still not removing the value. and the box still not checking or uncheck

Comment: not working select all or single checkbox ?

Comment: only the single checkbox, the select all working perfectly

Comment: @pandu added new logic with `Try 2`, please try with it

Comment: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')` i think when its reading prev when nothing is in selected2?

Comment: @pandu please share useState also

Comment: `const [selected2, setSelected2] = useState([]);` here

Comment: @pandu please console log `event.target.value` i think there is issue

Comment: evt.target.value log is exactly the value of the tradein id

Comment: @pandu added example, please follow code your issues will get fix

Comment: it worked. the problem is the value is in integer and the includes() checked is string. thanks for the help